# DotNetNuke 7 - Edit page menu not working when adding ajax control to module

Tags: asp.net, ajax, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am creating a simple DotNetNuke module and every time I add a control that contains ajax it somehow interferes with the edit page menu. The control in question is one from Syncfusion and it is the numeric textbox. 
The page and the menu functionality works well as long as I use the standard Microsoft user controls. For example if I change the ajax numeric textbox for the asp.net or the html one then it works well. As soon as I add the ajax textbox then the edit page menu does not work. 
Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Additional information: The Syncfusion control does not require any specific jQuery version.
There is no error logged on the DNN event viewer. I have been trying with FireBug to follow the tracks but it reveals nothing.
I have attached the screenshot to help visualize the issue.
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any specific javascript errors? Do the Syncfusion controls require a specific jquery version?

Comment: Worst case you can go to Host settings and switch the control bar back to the "Ribbon". Might help you figure out what the issue is or be a work around if that syncfusion module isn't working well with the new DNN 7 menu.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for pointing out that this could be a jQuery specific issue, it was a jQuery conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of jQuery conflicts. The syncfusion controls load their own jQuery library. To avoid issues within your module add a key to the appSettings section of the DNN web config file:

"SFjQueryLoad" value="false"

This will cause the control to use only the jQuery library provided by your DNN website.

Comment: You nailed it. I added the value to the web config file and it works so well now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have this same effect but as far as I know I do not use any syncfusion controls - could other jquery be causing conflicts?  -- I see nothing in the console for js errors